# Custom Javascript Variable Returns Different Value on History Change

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have setup a Custom JavaScript variable that works intermittently. The function is simply designed to return true or false if a text is contained on the page.

The below code works fine when the page is loaded directly from the URL bar and when executed in the developer tools console. When running the function in the console, the function indeed turns true. When the code is executed within debug mode in GTM, the value returns false when a history change event occurs.

```
function() {
  var content = document.body.innerText;
  var query = "text to search";
  if (content.search(query) > -1 ) {
   return true;
   } else {
   return false;
   }
}
```

Any assistance/insight is very much appreciated!

Comment: Its depends if the ``<script>`` is declared up or bottom of ``<body>`` element.

Comment: Is document.body.innerText already loaded when you fire the function? It might be undefined because of a race condition.

Comment: you have to call it as callback until the dom is ready. i suppose you are firing xhr requests on popstate? So you have to call it after readystatechange.

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems like expected behavior. Since you are talking about history changes, you are probably working with a single page application, or some other page where the DOM is changed after the initial page load.

Custom Javscript variables evaluate a function and return the result each time you reference it. How I imagine the flow of operations goes is this.

Page Loads (target text is in the page body) -> Custom JS evaluates on page view and returns true -> User presses some button -> DOM is modified to display new content (target text is removed and no longer present -> History change occurs -> Custom JS evaluates again, the text is no longer present so returns false.

If the target text is still present after the history change, then I can understand why we have some unexpected behavior. The [history change trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en) is based off of the [push state api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) so what could be happening is that the pushState() function is called before the DOM is finished being modified. In this case, the text isn't present at time of the history change event even though it is shortly afterwards.

You could change the page so pushState() is only called after the DOM is done being modified, use a custom event as a trigger instead (again, pushing it after the DOM is done being modified), or use a different trigger like the [element visibility trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679410?hl=en) that will only fire after the new DOM elements you want to target appear on-screen.